# Override Asp.Net Button mutators

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to trigger an event when Asp.Net button `visible` property is changed. For this purpose I am using `INotifyPropertyChanged`. The task remaining is to override getters and setters of button.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

MSDN site has given an example of implementing INotifyPropertyChanged interface when button click property changes. You can reference this example for achieving your goal.

Copied from MSDN -

> For change notification to occur in a binding between a bound client and a data source, your bound type should either:

```
Implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface (preferred).

Provide a change event for each property of the bound type.
```

Do not do both.

And to override getters and setters of button, this link will give you the necessary steps.
[INotifyPropertyChanged Example](http://aspdotnetblogspot.blogspot.in/2012/02/inotifypropertychanged-in-cnet.html?showComment=1345611473755#c934520258084600171)